# passing parameters to javascript function after function invocation?

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am making a function that returns an arbitrary term of a linear sequence. The test cases look like this:

```
Test.assertEquals(getFunction([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])(5), 5, "Nope! Try again.");
Test.assertEquals(getFunction([0, 3, 6, 9, 12])(10), 30, "Nope! Try again.");
Test.assertEquals(getFunction([1, 4, 7, 10, 13])(20), 61, "Nope! Try again.");
```

I don't understand the function invocation. I have written this code to determine the function of the linear sequence and compute an arbitrary term, but I don't know how to pass my function the term to compute:

```
function getFunction(sequence) {
  var diff = sequence[1] - sequence[0];
  var init = sequence[0];

  return diff*arguments[1]+init;
}
```

arguments[1] doesn't access the term passed in after the parameters. How can I access the term (5) in the first example?

```
Test.assertEquals(getFunction([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])(5), 5, "Nope! Try again.");
```

Comment: Your function must return a function.

Comment: you are only passing in your array to getFunction, there are no other arguments to get, hence why arguments[1] doesnt contain anything

Comment: As I read it, `getFunction([...])` returns a function which takes 5 in argument (for the first test case), you won't reach the argument `5` from `getFunction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a function from `getFunction()` in order to chain your function calls like your tests are expecting

Something like this:

```
function getFunction(sequence) {
  var diff = sequence[1] - sequence[0];
  var init = sequence[0];
  return function(num) {
     return diff*num+init;
  }
}
```

Comment: ahhh, so if I had an invocation like getSequence(stuff)(more stuff)(even more stuff); I would just have to keep nesting return statements that return functions?